# java, gameboard creating a unwanted new line

Tags: java, arrays

I really need help with this, I have wasted to much time figuring out. So I am trying to make a game where, gameboard is represented as array. Everything works perfectly execp when I reach the right side of the filed, new line is made created. Like that:

```
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
d
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
d
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
d
Invalid move
```

Invalid move

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleGame {
    static String [] board;
    int posy = 0;
    int EnemyY = 65;
public static void main(String [] args){
    String showField = " X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 \n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0      0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 M ";
    System.out.print(showField);
    System.out.print("");
    System.out.print("");
    String field = "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ";
    SimpleGame sg = new SimpleGame();
    while(true){
        sg.gamePlay(field);
    }
}
public void gamePlay(String field){
    field.trim();
    board = field.split(" ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("");
    int len = 11;
    String move = sc.nextLine();

    if(move.equals("d")){
        if(posy == 10 || posy == 21 || posy == 32 || posy == 43 || posy == 54 || posy == 65){
            System.out.println("Invalid move"); 
            return;
        }else{
            posy += 1;            
            board[posy] = "X";
        }
    }else if(move.equals("s")){
        if(55 <= posy  && posy <= 66){
            System.out.println("Invalid move"); 
            return;
        }else{
            posy += len;
            board[posy] = "X";
        }    
    }else if(move.equals("a")){
        if(posy == 0 || posy == 11 || posy == 22 || posy == 33 || posy == 44 || posy == 55){
            System.out.println("Invalid move"); 
            return;
        }else{
            posy -= 1;
            board[posy] = "X";   
        }    
    }else if(move.equals("w")){
        if(posy < 12){
            System.out.println("Invalid move"); 
            return;
        }else{
            posy -= len;
            board[posy] = "X";
        }
    }
    /*if(EnemyY == posy + len + 1 || posy == EnemyY + len + 1 || EnemyY == posy + len || posy == EnemyY +1 ){
        System.out.println("Game Over");
        return;
    }*/

    for (String board1 : board){
        System.out.print(board1);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}   
    public void addEnemy(int start, int x, int y, int [] board){

    }

}
```

Comment: [debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger)

Comment: Do you want to move that x to next line when you reaches right side of field? or what you want?

Comment: when it reaches the last 0 in the right side, the programm tells invalid move, and the user has to move somewhere else, the invalid move messages works though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You split your `field` string by spaces, therefore "0\n" is seen as one token. So when you replace the last element in your field, you also replace the new line.